# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) ng2-file-upload

Tags: angular, angular2-http

I am using Angular2-CLI 1.0.0-beta.28.3 I am using ng2-file-upload to upload my TXT file. However, I always got "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) " this error message. Right now, I am pretty sure I don't have system-config.ts file. So, I cannot use most solutions I found from the other website. Does anyone know what's wrong with my code?
Here is my component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FileUploader } from 'ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload';

const URL = 'http://XXx.xxx.xxx.xxx/amazonStatements/';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-arr',
  templateUrl: './arr.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./arr.component.css']
})
export class ARRComponent {
  private data: TbArr;
  private uploader:FileUploader = new FileUploader({url: URL});

  constructor() {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Here is my html file:

```
<div>
  <span style="float:left;padding:3px 12px;">Upload File:</span><span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
Choose File <input type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" accept="text/plain" multiple /></span>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-s" (click)="uploader.uploadAll()" [disabled]="!uploader.getNotUploadedItems().length">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload Now
            </button>
</div>
```

Here is the error message I got:
[image]

UPDATE MY QUESTION: 
This is my project folder structure:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post `systemjs.config.js`?

Comment: @Roman C, I don't have this file in my project folder.

Comment: @jmu 404 indicates that the client was able to communicate with a given server, but the server could not find what was requested.  Can you confirm what you're requesting actually exists? i.e correct path etc.

Comment: @jmu See my answer, I've recently implemented `file-uploader` into my project.

Comment: @CodeRatchet I am pretty sure the path is correct. Cause when I click the  url from console. That folder is showed up on my browser.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently implemented the `file-uploader` into my project, here's how I set it up:

Create a `FileUploaderOptions` variable, set the relevant properties inside that, then pass it into the `file-uploader`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FileUploader } from 'ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload';

const URL = 'http://XXx.xxx.xxx.xxx/amazonStatements/';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-arr',
  templateUrl: './arr.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./arr.component.css']
})
export class ARRComponent {
  private data: TbArr;
  private uploader:FileUploader;

  constructor() {
  }
  ngOnInit() {

      const uploaderOptions: FileUploaderOptions = {
            url: URL,
            autoUpload: false,
            isHTML5: true,
            removeAfterUpload: true,
        };

      this.uploader = new FileUploader(uploaderOptions);


  }

}
```

Comment: Right now, my url for website would be "http://XXX.XX.XX.XX/#/index" but the folder url would be "http://XXX.XX.XX.XX/amazonStatements/" Is it possible that cause the problem?